# php get_file_contents failing

Tags: php, csv, curl

I've inherited a PHP script which is simply trying to download a .csv file. However, it is not running as expected on the server that hosts the script.  On my PC the same script works fine:

Extract of the code below:

```
$file = 'myfile.csv';
$url = 'http://example.com/documents/myfile.csv';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
if(curl_exec($ch)!==FALSE){
    $urlValid = true;
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    print_r($info);
    $csv = file_get_contents($url);
    print_r($csv);
    $f = fopen('php://temp', 'r+');
    fwrite($f, $csv);
    rewind($f);
}
else{
    $urlValid = false;
    echo 'Url not valid'."\n";
    exit;
}
```

php.ini is set appropriately with `allow_url_fopen = On`

I've added some debug in - $info is returning the correct url, content_type and content_length but $csv is a generic html error page.

I can use `curl -O http://example.com/documents/myfile.csv` from the server and the file is downloaded as expected.

As mentioned I can run the script from my PC and the file is downloaded as expected.

I'm out of ideas :(

Versions that may help CentOS 5, PHP 5.1.6

Comment: Why you trying to use curl if writing `$csv = file_get_contents($url);`?

Comment: what does the generic error say? Have you tried to capture and show the result of `curl_exec()`?

Comment: Note that `curl` does not rely upon the `allow_url_fopen` configuration value, while `file_get_contents` does.

Comment: Try adding the useragent as a parameter to your curl request - and/or optionally as part of the `$context` argument to `file_get_contents`

Comment: @ineersa - not entirely sure, this is something I've inherited and is not working, unfortunately I'm not too familiar with PHP :(

Comment: @BeetleJuice - yes, the generic error is an HTML page that states in the body Javascript must be enabled in order to view this page.

Comment: @RamRaider - adding useragent doesn't make a difference to the curl request.  how would you suggest i added that to file_get_contents?

Comment: Sorry, should have read up, added the following which has worked:
`$options  = array('http' => array('user_agent' => 'custom user agent string'));
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);`